# Sequence contains more than one element - SingleOrDefault not helping

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have the line below but still get an exception "**Sequence contains more than one element**"

```
Details rd = this.db.Details.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TId == Id && x.TypeId == TypeId);
```

I was hoping that SingleOrDefault would avoid the exception.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`SingleOrDefault` returns a **SINGLE** element or null if no element is found.  If 2 elements are found in your Enumerable then it throws the exception you are seeing.  Just like Highlander... with Single - there can be only one.

`FirstOrDefault` returns the **FIRST** element it finds or null if no element is found.  so if there are 2 elements that match your predicate the second one is ignored.

Assuming you don't care if there are multiple matches and you only want the first one or null if no match is found... then you probably want the following...

```
Details rd = this.db.Details
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TId == Id && x.TypeId == TypeId);
```

Note that both of these methods only return one element they only differ in what they do after they find a match.  `First` stops looking at that point and returns what it found, `Single` keeps checking the rest of the list to make sure there are no more matches.  The `OrDefault` part determines what it returns if no match is found.  `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` returns null if no value is found but if you just use `Single` or `First` then it MUST find one match or it will throw an exception.

**EDIT: Good point Steve**
Since `First` returns the first element you may need to use an `OrderBy` in order to make sure the element you want is indeed first.  For instance... suppose your object had an UpdateDate property and you wanted the object with the most recent UpdateDate...

```
Details rd = this.db.Details
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdateDate)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TId == Id && x.TypeId == TypeId);
```

Comment: I would add the suggestion to the possibility to use an OrderBy

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having a list, convert the list to IEnumerable list, then you can make use of FirstOrDefault method

```
 IEnumerable<BuyOnlineSearchdetails> details = new List<BuyOnlineSearchdetails>();

var FirstRow = details.FirstOrDefault();
            string Count = "0";
            if (FirstRow != null)
            {
                Count = FirstRow.TotalCount.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Count = "0";
            }
```

Comment: Worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use FirstOrDefault()** instead of SingleOrDefault().

SingleOrDefault throws an exception if more than one element exists where as FirstOrDefault not.

Comment: This has already been explicitly explained in [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691622/sequence-contains-more-than-one-element-singleordefault-not-helping#answer-22691701).