# How to reference a window using a variable

Tags: c#, wpf, reference, window

I've created some windows dynamically, and named them dynamically, using data from an SQL database. Now I want to reference them using data from a label that has been clicked on. Below is a basic example.

```cs
private void buildWindow(string contentFromDataBase)
{
    Window fooWindow = new Window();
    fooWindow.Name = contentFromDataBase + "Window"
}

//Event handler for a label being clicked
private void showWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Now I want to get access to fooWindow via it's name, which is similar to the label name
  Label foo = sender as Label;
  foo.Name + "Window".show();
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to search `Application.Current.Windows` for your `Window` by it's `Name` property.

```
var targetWindow = Application.Current.Windows
    .Cast<Window>()
    .Where(window => window.Name == String.Concat(foo.Name, "Window"))
    .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
    .Single();

if (targetWindow != null)
   targetWindow.Show();
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Application.Windows.get'". The intellisense isn't giving me Windows or Where when typing that in, am I missing an assembly reference or something?

Comment: Sorry, need to use `Application.Current.Windows`. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's now saying System.Windows.WindowCollection does not contain a definition for Where

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` in top of your file @JamesR

Answer (score 0):

Store your windows in a list or a dictionary. And then you can get your window via the label name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case LINQ `.Where` did not work. So I tried a different way

```cs
private LoginScreen LoginScreenWindowInstance = (LoginScreen)Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(window => window.Name == "LoginScreenWindow");
```

Where `.Name` is the `x:Name` property of the window and (LoginScreen) is referred to the window from which you can inherit properties and change object. For example, if you want to retrieve the value of an object found in (LoginScreen) window you can simply type

```
LoginScreenWindowInstance.Textbox1.Text
```

Keep in mind the use of `FirstOrDefault` vs `SinglOrDefault`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22691701/14456332) is a good explanation

Comment: `Where()` would of course also work with `.OfType<Window>()` or `.Cast<Window>()`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Clemens. I have seen that you edited also the accepted answer. Best regards :)